# How to update all libraries in Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm updating a spring boot project from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3.
the parent maven pom has a lot of the dependencies locked down to a specific version in the dependencyManagement section, like this, for example:

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${netflix.feign.jackson.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

Is this supposed to be the normal procedure, to lock down all versions once you get it working?

And in my case, when updating to spring boot 3, What is the best procedure to update all libraries? do I need to comment out everything in the dependencyManagement section to re-establish compatibility with Spring Boot 3?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried and ask one specific question at a time. The answer largely depends on you project, to keep it short you it will probably work to simply update spring boot and nothing else but ideally you should update and keep all your dependencies to the latest versions whenever possible.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking down versions in the dependencyManagement section is generally considered good practice for stability and conflict resolution. Upgrading a Spring Boot project can be a challenging task.

For custom dependencies locked down in dependencyManagement, consult the documentation for each dependency to see if they're compatible with Spring Boot 3. Update their versions as needed. Update the version one by one, testing each time to ensure nothing breaks. Also, make sure all your unit tests and integration tests pass.

Also read these articles carefully: https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide

As I said this task could be challenging and tedious, it depends how many dependencies in general you have in your project.